# How do I add 3V plug in power to a 3.5mm lavalier microphone?

Tags: preamp

I'm trying to hook a cheap lavalier microphone to a Behringer HA400 micro preamp.  The input line does not provide any power to the microphone.
The microphone works fine when powered by a sound card with 3V in a PC.  How do I add 3V to the tip of a 3.5mm jack?
I don't need a filter, amp (that's what I'm hooking it to...) or anything else.  Just plug in power.

Comment: Voted to close since your comments have made clear that you are looking for a completed device rather than help desigining/building the device your self.  There are commercial units available.  Search for phantom power adapters for electret microphones.  Note the keywords: phantom power, electret microphone, adapter.

Comment: @JRE I would *rather* have a commercial device, but it looks like there is no such thing, so this is still open.
Also, the information is still valid, regardless of my personal intentions.  It has value to leave it here for others going down the same road and ending up building it themselves.

Comment: Also note...this is *not* phantom power.  This is plug in power, which is a totally different standard, and the search you mention doesn't come up with any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard electret bias network is simply a 1.5V - 3V battery with a 2k2 or so resistor in series.

Connect the sleeve connection to ground and connect the free end of the resistor to the plug tip connconnection. The tip connection also feeds the preamp input.

You may need a DC blocking capacitor in series with the preamp input. Most preamp inputs contain their own DC block capacitors internally but some don't. A capacitor value anywhere from 1uF or so is good: (+) side of the cap goes to the mic / bias resistor; the (-)  side of the cap goes to the preamp input.